# Entity Framework Core: check constraint generates invalid SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework-core

I am using the newest EF Core with Oracle DB provider and trying to add a check constraint to a column.

This is the code I have:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(t => t.HasCheckConstraint("Osoba_CHk_Email", "email like '_%@_%._%'"));      
}
```

When I execute the migration it fails with error:

> ORA-06550: line 10, column 53:
> PLS-00103: "_" symbol found in a situation where one of the following options was assumed:
>
> - & = - + ; < / > at v is mod remainder not rem return
>   returning <exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
>   like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk member
>   submultiset

The problem is with the SQL it generates:

```sql
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE
         "Osoba" (
              "email" NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
              CONSTRAINT "Osoba_CHk_Email" CHECK (email like '_%@_%._%')
)';
END;
```

In particular, this part:

```
(email like '_%@_%._%')
```

Because the `CREATE TABLE` is in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` the `'` symbol after the like violates the syntax.

How can I solve this issue?

One possible solution is to add manually `migrationBuilder.Sql(...)` to the migration's `Up` method. However, I am wondering whether there is another solution which doesn't require modification of the auto-generated migration.

Comment: Try escaping the quotes: "email like ''_%@_%._%''" using double-single quotes. (quote quote).

The issue is that you do need to consider that to run the migrations EF is going to need to create an EXECUTE statement so any single quotes you want to pass into the expression will need to be escaped in a way that your provider's generated SQL will have the database engine understand. That may involve some trial and error with reviewing what EF is outputting.

Comment: @wujido Do yo mind posting your solution as an answer, so that others who might stumble upon this can build upon your knowledge?